# slidestop for a single slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to align text at the top of the slide for only a single slide?

Alternatively is there a simple way to absolute align anything in a beamer slide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the optional arguments `t` and `c` of the `beamer` class resp. its `frame` environment.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```