# Positioning content at the top of a beamer slide (by default)

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

When I create beamer frame, the content is centred in the slide. How do I make the content move to the top of the slide by default?

Comment: Related: [slidestop for a single slide in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6830/1235).

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You could specify vertical top alignment globally by the `t` class option:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
```

For single frames you could use the same option locally:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Question: I'm using a template with the following preamble: "\documentclass[t]{beamer}

%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
% or ...

\usecolortheme{orchid}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{}
" and when I'm adding \document"class[t]{beamer} and compiling, it says "\documentclass[t]{
                       beamer}
The document may only declare one class.
". What have I done wrong? EDIT: I'm working in LyX.

Comment: @Pandora Go to Document -> Settings -> Document Class, there choose beamer, and add `t` as class option, that single letter.

Comment: Note: if the frame has a title, place the `[t]` before it: `\begin{frame}[t]{My Frame Title}`

Comment: If you are using `\againframe` (as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371501/temporarily-suspend-stepwise-beamer-presentation-to-show-full-slide-of-code-list/371504), place the `[t]` after the `<4->`, e.g.: `\againframe<4->[t]{important}`

Answer (score 10):

For those writing beamer themes: The class option `t` is stored in `\beamer@centered`. So `\beamer@centeredfalse` and `beamer@centeredtrue` will change the default vertical alignment for frames and columns.