# LyX White Space on Slide

Tags: tables, beamer, lyx

Using LyX I find that there is always so much white space between the figure and the the slide title and between the table caption and the table. Is there a way to reduce this space in the preamble?

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup{skip=5pt}`

Comment: @hpesoj626 Thanks for the quick response. Any idea on the first question? The white space between the caption and the slide title is enough to fit the word Table 2 times, I would like to reduce this space by at least half.

Comment: I can't say for sure. Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of the code from LyX?

Comment: @hpesoj626 I am using the beamer template with no additional packages or code. Just pasting trying to get this white space minimized globally

Comment: Try `\documentclass[t]{beamer}`. I think this is a duplicate of [Positioning content at the top of a beamer slide (by default)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9889). Please see if this solves your problem :)