# LyX Beamer [t] on plaint itle frame

Tags: beamer, lyx, vertical-alignment

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9889/positioning-content-at-the-top-of-a-beamer-slide-by-default/9890#9890), I read how to set [t] globally for a beamer template in LyX. However, is it also possible to just set the [t] option for the PLAIN TITLE frame and leave centering for all other?

Best,
Fabian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of LyX 2.1.0, put the cursor at the beginning of the frame (so your layout should say "Frame"), then go to Insert > Frame Options and put in 't'.

For more information, please read the LyX Beamer guide under Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations.