# Temporarily suspend stepwise beamer presentation to show full slide of code listing or graphic

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is it possible to suspend a stepwise presentation to show a full slide containing say code listings (or a graphic). I don't want the full slide to cover the slide title.

```
\begin{frame}{Really important stuff}
    \begin{itemize}
        \pause
        \item Version control

        \pause
        \item Architecture

        %%% Want to show a full side of listings at this point 
        %%% then return to the stepwise presentation
        \pause
        \item Documentation

        \pause
        \item Personal development
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: @samcarter I guessed so, I just couldn't find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, using `\againframe` and overlay specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-3>[label=important]{Really important stuff}
    \begin{itemize}
        \pause
        \item Version control

        \pause
        \item Architecture

        %%% Want to show a full side of listings at this point 
        %%% then return to the stepwise presentation
        \pause
        \item Documentation

        \pause
        \item Personal development
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Really important listing}
Listing goes here \ldots
\end{frame}

\againframe<4->{important}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I do this several times in one slide. I've tried adding another `frame` and `\againframe` but the second listing is not appearing where expected.

Comment: @Olumide you need to change the overlay specification accordingly, e.g. `\againframe<4>{...}`, then the frame with the second listing and then `\againframe<5->{...}`

Comment: I've edited the previous specification to `\againframe<4>{important}` and added \againframe<6->{important}. It sort of works although I'm just getting the hang of what `againframe` means i.e. returns to item.