# Beamer : Do not center vertically text in frame

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I am using the beamer class and consider the following frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item blabla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It appears that the text "blabla" is vertically centered on the slide.
I would like to avoid this so that this text "blabla" appears on the first
line of the slide.

A global change on all slides is suitable for me.

Thanks

Comment: [Positioning content at the top of a beamer slide (by default)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9889/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: indeed it's a duplicate